# Facebook Offline post to stream

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have read alot about publish_stream and offline_access.

1.) User connects on my website.
2.) I can now post on he's wall with the API on the user (userid saved in database)

But what if user sign out of Facebook and come back on my website? Then the user has to "accept"/"login" again, but it has to be logged in automatcitly, so i in the future can post to the facebook wall of the user.

Do i have to save access_token, user_id in database, what else? I cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the access token and user ID. The access tokens are valid for 1 to 2 hours, but they can be exchanged with long-lived ones which are valid for 30 days. The offline_access permission is deprecated and will be removed by December 5th.

How to extend the access token: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 0):

you just need the user_id and access_token stored in your database, and then u can use this to post whenever you want. but have in mind that the token expires after some time.

[solution](http://eagerfish.eu/using-facebook-off-line-access-to-post-on-users-wall/)